# Найти индекс элемента в списке списков

Tags: python, list

Есть два списка списков:

```py
List1=[['aaa', '9', 'ddd', '10'], ['ddd', '12', 'hhh', '3'], ['uuu', '8', 'hhh', '15']]
List2=[['uuu', 0, 0, 0, 0], ['hhh', 0, 0, 0, 0], ['ddd', 0, 0, 0, 0], ['aaa', 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Наполнение второго списка происходит через первый, но должна быть привязка к строкам, в данном примере `List2[3][0]` должен быть связан с `List1[0][0]`.

Собственно вопрос: как получить индекс `list2`, зная `list1`?
Или поумнее какой вариант предложите?

```
if int(List1[0][1]) < int(List1[0][3]):
    List2[2][1] += 1
    List2[2][4] += 5
    List2[3][3] += 1
```

Не знаю как обратится к нужным строкам ‘List2’, изначально не известно, на каких строках будут находится ‘aaa’, ‘ddd’...

Comment: BTW у вас переменные в одном месте называются с большой буквы, в другом с маленькой (не говоря уже про пеп8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
List1=[['aaa', '9', 'ddd', '10'], ['ddd', '12', 'hhh', '3'], ['uuu', '8', 'hhh', '15']]
List2=[['uuu', 0, 0, 0, 0], ['hhh', 0, 0, 0, 0], ['ddd', 0, 0, 0, 0], ['aaa', 0, 0, 0, 0]]


res = [f"{x[0]}: {np.argwhere(np.array(List1)==x[0]).tolist()}" for x in List2]
```

res:

```
['uuu: [[2, 0]]', 'hhh: [[1, 2], [2, 2]]', 'ddd: [[0, 2], [1, 0]]', 'aaa: [[0, 0]]']
​
```

**UPDATE**

Если вам нужно получить индексы подсписков, с которыми вам нужно работать по вашему условию, то можете сделать так:

```
idx = [y[0] for y in [(np.argwhere(np.array(List2)[:,0]==x[0])).flatten() for x in List1 if int(x[1]) < int(x[3])]]
```

а затем работать со вторым списком в соответствии с отобранными индексами. Например, так:

```
for i in idx:
    List2[i][1]="foo"
```

(получите такой List2):

```
[['uuu', 'foo', 0, 0, 0],
 ['hhh', 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ['ddd', 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ['aaa', 'foo', 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Похоже я не так сформулировал вопрос. If Int(List1([0][1]))<int(List1([0][3])) надо начать заполнять строку List2([2][0]). Как к ней обратится, зная только что в List2 где то есть значение “ddd” и оно точно находится в 0 вом столбце

Comment: idx = [y[0] for y in [(np.argwhere(np.array(List2)[:,0]==x[0])).flatten() for x in List1 if int(x[1]) < int(x[3])]]   То что надо но на фоне остального кода эта строчка будет смотреться как инопланетное вторжение. Можно её попроще написать? Желательно без импортов

Comment: Проще - только циклами. Вам CrazyElf ответил.

Comment: Проверил, немного не так работает, надо чтобы еще в “hhh” foo  записал, т.е. для всех «меньших» сравнений

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой вопрос так, чтобы было сразу ясно, что именно вам требуется.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, примерно так простым перебором:

```
list1=[['aaa', '9', 'ddd', '10'], ['ddd', '12', 'hhh', '3'], ['uuu', '8', 'hhh', '15']]
list2=[['uuu', 0, 0, 0, 0], ['hhh', 0, 0, 0, 0], ['ddd', 0, 0, 0, 0], ['aaa', 0, 0, 0, 0]]

for i11,l11 in enumerate(list1):
    for i12,l12 in enumerate(l11):
        for i21,l21 in enumerate(list2):
            for i22,l22 in enumerate(l21):
                if l12 == l22:
                    print(f'list2[{i21}][{i22}] -> list1[{i11}][{i12}]')
```

Вывод:

```
list2[3][0] -> list1[0][0]
list2[2][0] -> list1[0][2]
list2[2][0] -> list1[1][0]
list2[1][0] -> list1[1][2]
list2[0][0] -> list1[2][0]
list2[1][0] -> list1[2][2]
```